# complete.cases function in R not working

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) like the following:

```
M4, 2007-05-03T09:00:00Z,1021.2,50,12, NaN,12.2,84
M4, 2007-05-03T10:00:00Z,1021.6,50,10, NaN,12.3,84
M4, 2007-05-03T11:00:00Z,1020.8,50,9, NaN,12.4,84
M4, 2007-05-03T12:00:00Z,1021.8,50,9, NaN,12.3, NaN
M4, 2007-05-03T13:00:00Z,1021.8,40,10, NaN,12.3,86
M4, 2007-05-03T14:00:00Z,1021.6,40,11, NaN,12,89
M4, 2007-05-03T15:00:00Z,1021.6,40,12,18,10.1,92
M4, 2007-05-03T16:00:00Z,1021.2,40,10,16,10,94
M4, 2007-05-03T17:00:00Z,1021,30,11,16,10.2,94
```

I dont understand, why the following statement doesnt have any effect. The number of observations is still the same and in the "cleaned" dataset, the NaN values still appears.

```
df.clean <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Your code works for me. It gives me a dataframe with 3 observations.

Comment: What do you get when you do `is.na(df[1,6])`? It should return `TRUE`. If not something went wrong when reading your table.

Comment: The statement `is.na(df[1,6])` returns `FALSE`. I cannot see any problem when reading the data it comes from a csv. file: `df <- read.csv("M4_not_cleaned.csv", header=TRUE)`

Comment: thanks to hugo, the problem was coming from the import file. That contains two header lines. After I've deleted one header line, the code was working. Thanks or the hints.